# Jquery to add to form when other is selected in drop box

Tags: jquery

ok i have a drop box in a form gives you the page names of each of web pages the last selection is Other. What i want to do is when other is selected i want to use jquery to add a text field into it. i know how to make the div and put the text field in there but how do make it work?

oh yea i also know how to make the acording box so i dont need that info just not shure where to put the javascript:togglecontainer() command

Answer (score 0):

You can call [jQuery.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on the drop box, and append the text field accordingly.

So you can do something like this

```
$("#drop-box").live("change", function(){
 if($(this).val() == "Other")
    $("#text-field-div").show();
 else
    $("#text-field-div").hide();
});
```

Comment: not realy what i was looking for i have a div thats hidden right below the drop down box i need to know what command to put in the <option> to get it to run my script to open that div i have a script already!!

Comment: I didn't quite understand. You have a div that is hidden which has the text-field, and you want to run the function to show the text-field when the option is set to "Other"? I've tried to modify my answer to fit this scenario